# Setting UIImageView equal to another UIImageView in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

So I want to set the image of one image view equal to the image of another image view. I have the following code below, but am experiencing errors:

```
imageView1.image = imageView2.image;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you want to set same image for both imageView? If yes, then are you setting image to imageView2 first?

Comment: Which error are you experiencing?

Comment: first you have to know which size is fix for all. then just setting one image size fixed and did what @PayalManiyar suggest on her answer. and reply asap about all answer

Answer (score 0):

U can use statement like this

```
[imageView1 setImage:imageView2.image];
```

Answer (score 0):

What errors did you get? 
This should normally work:

```
self.imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.png"];
self.imageView1.image = self.imageView2.image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below line of code

```
[imageView1.image setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:(imageView2.image.CGImage)]];
```